# Windows volume mix low, even though source application is maxed

Tags: windows-7, firefox, audio

On some, but not all, sites in Firefox, the sound output is quite low.  Upon investigating, the VU meter built into the sound mixer shows that all channels are maxed (sound output and Firefox sliders are at the top), and the VU meter for Firefox shows a very loud signal, but the VU meter for the speakers is only showing about half the volume (see picture below).

[image]

I have turned off all enhancements in the sound card properties, so that is NOT the case.  All the levels in the sound card properties (there is only one) are maxed.  This happens with both the on board Realtek audio, and a Lexicon Alpha USB studio interface.  Sites include those that do NOT use plugins (it happens with HTML5).

What could be the problem here, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Since I have installed Windows 10, I am unable to reproduce this behavior.  Since I cannot test for a best answer (as I upgraded out of the problem), I cannot award a best answer.

Comment: Have you found the answer? Thanks

Comment: @Ooker No, the problem persisted throughout my use of windows 7.  I have, however, switched to windows 10 in the mean time, which does not have this issue.  I guess the answer is "Install windows 10"

Comment: I am having this with Windows 10 though

Comment: @Ooker It might be helpful to ask a separate question.  The change in operating systems is sufficient to justify a new question, especially considering this is an issue with software/OS inter-operation.

Comment: I'm also having this exact problem on Windows 10. I think it only happened after an update, as my sound was fine (my laptop was actually unusually loud), then suddenly one day everything was quiet. And I can see exactly this, the speaker device is 50% of the app.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to *have been* a bug in the Adobe Flash player when used in Firefox in some cases. See https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1075605. There is a similar issue now, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1005135, with multiple suggestions for resolution.

Comment: In my case, this is unhelpful.  The sites i have the most problems with are HTML5.

Answer (score -2):

Try selecting a diffrent microphone as standard or deactivating them all together. If you use the switching method, I did have to repeat the switch for every new video I selected, so you might have to do the same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBq4ISM17HI

Comment: This is not correct.